# Progress bar on scroll not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, scroll

I'm trying to create a progress bar that fills on scroll. I used a piece of code that I found in W3Schools and made a few changes (and it worked in this code snippet but not on my [page](https://crvlh.com/work/brand-identity-flor-de-lima/)).

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.header h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#progressBar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
  <div id="progressBar"></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Scroll Down to See The Effect</h3>
  <p>We have created a "progress bar" to <b>show how far a page has been scrolled</b>.</p>
  <p>It also <b>works when you scroll back up</b>.</p>
  <p>It is even <b>responsive</b>! Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: correct would be after the function definition: `window.onscroll = myFunction`  but it still wont work on your page, no clue. You are including 12 Javascript-ressources that could have eventually changed the default  behaviour

Comment: People who could help you (like myself) don't want to click-through to your link and debug your website (I get paid for that). You will have to provide the relevant code here on SO.

Comment: @johnSmith I don't know if this helps but I just notice that in this pages (https://crvlh.com/contacts/ and https://crvlh.com/about/) if I change a div size to `height: 200vh;`the progress bar works

Comment: @mattavatar In the original question I have placed my code but it was edited to this...

Comment: Okay, I combed through the edits looking for something the editor may have changed... but, they did everything right. All they did was format and copy your code from codepen into SO. I saw in an earlier edit performed by you that you fixed a syntax error where you were using square brackets instead of braces as function enclosures -- did you also fix this in your code on your site?

Comment: The frustrating fact is that if it works on SO but not on your website then you are just not ready to receive help from the SO community. The question has to be contained within SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I answer this based on the website you provided, not on the actual code you provided.

if you change your css for `<section>`

from:

```
height:100vh;
```

to

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

it is working without breaking anything  ;-) cheers